# C# - Inter-process Communication using Named Pipes (What Am I Doing Wrong?)

Tags: c#, wpf, ipc, named-pipes, launcher

I'm trying to use IPC to allow my application to be opened exclusively via launcher. And for that I decided to use named pipes to pass a "request" and open my main application's login window after updates and checksum are done, but I'm quite new to C# and have run into some issues that I just can't seem to find where they're originating from...

After all updates are done and the launcher creates & request the application to open, the main application opens and then immediately closes without any error messages/logs. But if I try to open the application independently then it opens (And stays that way) but only in the processes' list, which by itself is another huge problem...

## **Launcher Side - MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
private static async Task StarterAsync()
{
    string executablePath = "Application.exe";

    try
    {
        Process.Start(executablePath);

        using NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new("MyAppNP", PipeDirection.Out);
        await pipeServer.WaitForConnectionAsync();

        byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("LaunchRequest");
        await pipeServer.WriteAsync(messageBytes);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```

## **Main Application Side - App.xaml.cs:**

```
namespace MyApp
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            string pipeName = "MyAppNP";
            using NamedPipeServerStream pipeServer = new(pipeName, PipeDirection.In);

            try
            {
                pipeServer.WaitForConnection();

                byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
                int bytesRead = pipeServer.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

                if (message == "LaunchRequest")
                {
                    Login.Login loginWindow = new();
                    loginWindow.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Launcher request mismatch. Exiting the application.");

                    pipeServer.Close();
                    Current.Shutdown();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);

                pipeServer.Close();
                Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone with more experience help me find what is causing all these issues to happen?

**I tried:**

- I checked some logs but couldn't find anything related to these problems.
- I didn't try any debugging yet, I'm just too frustrated and want nothing more than to distance myself from anything code-related for the next 12 hours xD

**I was expecting:**

- That after the launcher was done updating/checking important files it'd then send the request for the main application to open, when it did it'd close itself.
- After that the Main application would run normally as it was before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both sides are creating a `NamedPipeServerStream` and waiting for the other side to connect; one of those should be `NamedPipeClientStream` and establishing the connection.

Alternatively, you can use anonymous pipes (`ProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput` and friends). That's a more common approach when you have a parent/child process relationship.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

10+ hours working + inexperience can really lead to some silly mistakes...

Answer (score 0):

Since the community could help me, I feel like I should post the corrected code, maybe this will help someone with a similar problem in the future:

**Main Application side (Fixed):**

```cs
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);

    string pipeName = "MyAppNP";

    try
    {
        using NamedPipeClientStream pipeClient = new(".", pipeName, PipeDirection.In);
pipeClient.Connect();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int bytesRead = pipeClient.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);

            if (message == "LaunchRequest")
            {
                
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Launcher request mismatch. Exiting the application.");
                Current.Shutdown();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        Current.Shutdown();
    }
}
```